# Fill down in Excel, but based on multiple values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have spreadsheets (not created by me) that have blank entries in one column where they should really have data. I want to take every empty cell and fill it with the *nearest* value above it. I'm looking for as little manual intervention as possible, because I'll have to do it repeatedly.

I thought some previous version of Excel, or maybe another spreadsheet from the distant past, would do this by default -- that is, if you selected the column with foo and bar, and chose the equivalent of "fill down", you would get what's in the WANT column. What I actually get in Excel is the GET column.

```
HAVE:            WANT:           GET:
foo     1        foo     1       foo     1
        2        foo     2       foo     2
bar     1        bar     1       foo     1
        2        bar     2       foo     2
        3        bar     3       foo     3
```

I'm worried that this might need a macro to be done properly. I used to be a whiz with Excel macros, and then suddenly they were all in VB.

My fallback position will be to dump the whole thing to CSV and write a Python script, but if there's any way to do it in Excel that would be much preferable. Even if it involves a couple of different manual steps, that's fine; just not one step per group of lines. That is, a process of "copy the column, do X to it, cut and paste it back" would work, but "do X for each occurrence of foo or bar" won't. The files are too big for that.

Any thoughts are appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Mr. Excel](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/fill-excel-blank-rows-macro.php) has the answer for pre-Ribbon versions of Excel. Below are instructions for Excel 2007. With foo/bar in column A and your data in column B:

1. Select all of the data in column A, from top to bottom.
2. Click on Home->Find & Select->Go To Special
3. Click "Blanks" and hit "Ok". (*At this point, all blanks in the column should be selected, and cell A2 should be the active cell.*)
4. Press "=", and then press up to select cell A1.
5. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy the formula into all selected cells.

*Optional Step 7*: If you need only the values, copy the whole column and "Paste Special" just values over top.

Comment: This didn't work exactly as presented, but the referenced page got me there. Thanks! Sorry for not responding for so long -- stackoverflow sends me email but apparently superuser doesn't.

Comment: I just happened to need to do this again, and decided to try again. I had no difficulties. Do you know which step(s) caused problems for you?

Comment: This is super handy.  One thing I noticed, the reference cell (e.g. =A1 in this case), must be "General" format.  It didn't work if it was "Text".  Drove me crazy for a time.  Yes, I know this is from a hundred years ago...still gold.

Answer (score 2):

To do it manually:

Add a column (B) between the foo-bar column (say A) and the number column (now C).

Formula in B1 is something like `=A1`, in B2 (and copied down to the end of the data) `=if(A2="",B1,A2)`. Column B now has the foo-bars almost as you want them, but they are the result of formulae rather than text.

Copy column B and `paste special` it into column A as values.

You can now delete column B.

If you get the idea, it's probably quicker to do it than write down the description, but whether you would prefer a Python script or not will depend on the number of spreadsheets...

Answer (score 0):

There is actually an easier way to do this without having to copy the entire row you need to drop down values.

Create a new Column, Use the =IFBLANK() Function and follow the steps similar to an =IF() Function.

Basically =ifblank(Value if true (the cell above), (value if false(same cell))....