# Whats an easy way to fill in empty cells after copy and pasting from Pivot table classic layout?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I've run a report on products sold and used a pivot table to see products by customer. I then need to upload the data back to SF and so I have used the classic pivot table layout to be able to copy and paste into a new sheet as shown below.

Whats an easy way of filling in all the gaps other than manually copying and pasting? In this case I have about 200 rows but I have some more where I'll have 20,000+

Some items in colum A end in numbers but all are unique identifiers. Column B values are unique for each value in column A

Basically the problem is - If cell in Column A is blank fill using previous non blank value above.

[Link to screenshot of problem on imgur as I don't have reputation to post one :(](https://imgur.com/PeqxtgR)

Answer (score 1):

You can fill in the blanks afterwards as described in this [question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/151057/fill-down-in-excel-but-based-on-multiple-values) or you can get your pivot table to repeat them for you before you copy/paste.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Mike. Appreciate the answer - sorry I can't vote up :(